# VBA: Replace double linebreak

Tags: excel, vba, replace

i am trying to replace a multiple linebreak within a string in vba.

```
'mystring
I am a 


string
```

The double linebreak should be replaced by some text.

```
Dim str As String
Dim str_new As String

str = Cells(1, 1).Value

str = Replace(str, "Chr(10) Chr(10)", "<p>")

Cells(2, 1).Value = str_new
```

It works perfectly fine for a single linebreak:

```
str = Replace(str, "Chr(10)", "<br>")
```

That's why i assume there is a problem with "Chr(10) Chr(10)". I already tried different types e.g. "Chr(10)&Chr(10)"...

Anyone may help how to fecht a bouble linebreak in vba?

Comment: Surprised that it works for a single linebreak character. Try: `str = Replace(str, Chr(10) & Chr(10), "<p>")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is slightly more complete:

```
Sub DoubleReturns()
    Dim s As String

    s = Chr(10) & Chr(10)
    Cells(2, 1) = Replace(Cells(1, 1), s, "<p>")
End Sub
```

For example:

[image]